# Is there a difference in requiring a json file in vscode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I got a test1.ts file, it has only one line:

```
var x = require('./temp2.json')
```

this has no warning in VSCode, but when I have a similar code in test2.js:

```
var x = require('./temp2.json')
```

It trigger an warning: [js] can not find module './temp2.json', why?
btw checkJs is true in jsconfig.json

Comment: Did you checked the relative path of test2.js ? maybe it is in different folder ?

Comment: in the same folder

Comment: @AngeloC Might it be just `temp2.json` instead of `./temp2.json`?

Comment: changed to temp2.json, same, ts no warning while js has

Comment: if tsc test1  then mv test1.js test1b.js, the generated file has the exact content of test2.js and also has the warning, conclusion is, ignore the warning if require a json file in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug as of VS Code 1.16 / TypeScript 2.5. The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15987)

There was [a PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13665) out for the parent issue however it has not been updated recently so I'm not aware of its status